# Create directory in file system per organic group

Tags: 7, organic-groups, files

I am using Drupal 7 and I am creating a content type which is a content of an Organic Group. This content type has a file field and all the Organic Group Members can create a node of that. I want to grouping the files in the file system with directories automatically named by Organic Groups names and some sub directories named by current date and current user uid. User can be member of 2 or more groups, so the file should be copied to all the groups directories that user selects in the create node form. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [Filefield Paths](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module will do what you ask, in particular there is an over view on how to [Mix public and private files with Organic Groups and File (Field) Paths](https://drupal.org/node/1919154)

The part I can see it doing is copying the file - but you may not want that behavior as it will quickly bloat your storage.